# I Want To know The Thymeleaf Variable Location In Featured Products In Broadleaf

Tags: broadleaf-commerce

I Want To know What is the location of Thymeleaf variables in broadleaf home page. Please Help Me to Solve the Problem.

Here is the screenshot of the file and locaion:

file Screenshot: https://prnt.sc/gwtqun

i want to know the location of #object and featured products on that screen shot.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Thymeleaf, the `*` and the `#object` both refer to the selected object in that context. http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#expressions-on-selections-asterisk-syntax

In the HeatClinic demo, the `productListItem.html` template is referenced within several other templates where there are lists of products, such as groups of featured products, categories, and search.

For example, in `search.html`:

```
<ul th:if="${products}" id="products" class="js-products group">
    <li th:each="product : ${products}" th:object="${product}" th:include="catalog/partials/productListItem" class="js-productContainer productContainer"></li>
</ul>
```

Here you can see within the multiple nested instances of `productListItem`, the  will be each of the products from the search. Those products are set on the model from the `BroadleafSearchController` by a call to `model.addAttribute(...)`.

---

Edit: In the HeatClinic demo's `homepage.html` in particular:

```
<li th:if="${pageFields[product1]} and ${pageFields[product1].isActive()}" th:with="product=${pageFields[product1]}"
        th:object="${pageFields[product1]}" th:include="catalog/partials/productListItem"
        class="js-productContainer productContainer"></li>
```

The `pageFields` attribute comes from the database table `BLC_PAGE_FLD`, where there is an entry with the key `product1` and a value which is the product ID of the desired product (for example `1` in the demo). The controller which adds this object to the model is the `BroadleafPageController`.

Comment: ok thankyou @epenning i want to know one more information from you if i want to add some other type of products like (merchadise men) to the home page where can i find the details to add that products to the home page and where can i add the code and where can i find the classes of those products . please help me to solve the issue thanks in advance